# Powershell and SQL: How to store the value of a query in a variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell

I wrote a powershell script that runs two SQL queries, saves the result in 2 variables and compares them. I receive an email if the results are different from one another.
However, I noticed that the results are always the same. When I Write-Host the two variables, I get this: `System.Data.DataRow`. I assume that when I compare the two variables, I am actually comparing `System.Data.DataRow` to `System.Data.DataRow`.

The IF I use is quite simple:

```
if ($resultDB = $resultCube) {$SMTPClient.Send( $emailMessageSuccess )} ELSE {$SMTPClient.Send( $emailMessageFailure )}
```

Am I doing it wrong, or is there a way to store the actual value of an SQL query in a variable?
When I Write-Output the variables, I get:

```
Column1  
-------  
993991
```

That number is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens, as assignment and comparison operators are mixed. In Powershell, `=` is assignment and `-eq` is equal comparison. Thus,

```
if ($resultDB = $resultCube) { ... }
```

is parsed as

```
if $resultCube was assigned into $resultDB without any issues, do...
```

If you wonder how assignment could fail, consider read-only variables:

```
New-Variable -Name myConstant -Value 1
$myConstant
1
if($myConstant = 2) { "aye"} else { "nay" } # Try and assign new value
aye
$myConstant # It works
2
Remove-Variable -Name myconstant
New-Variable -Name myConstant -Value 1 -Option readonly # Now, let's try with a read-only variable
if($myConstant = 2) { "aye"} else { "nay" } # Kaboom!
Cannot overwrite variable myConstant because it is read-only or constant.
At line:1 char:4
+ if($myConstant = 2) { "aye"} else { "nay" }
+    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (myConstant:String) [], SessionStateUnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : VariableNotWritable
```

As how to compare column values, try something akin

```
if ($resultDB["myColumn"] -eq $resultCube["myColumn"]) { ... }
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't have much experience with Powershell, so this was perfect. I learned something today :)